# PDF File to Dict Returns Weird Characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pdfminer

I am trying to create a program that utilizes pdfminer to read a DnD Character Sheet (fillable PDF) and put the fill-ins into a dictionary. Upon editing the PDF and running the program again, I get a strange sequence of characters when printing the dictionary items. The code:

```py
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1
import collections

filename = "Edited_CS.pdf"
fp = open(filename, 'rb')
my_dict = {}

parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']

# Checks if PDF file is blank
if isinstance(fields, collections.abc.Sequence) is False:
    print("This Character Sheet is blank. Please submit a filled Character Sheet!")

else:
    for i in fields:
        field = resolve1(i)
        name, value = field.get('T'), field.get('V')
        if value is None or str(value)[2:-1] == "":
            value = "b'None'"
        my_dict[str(name)[2:-1]] = str(value)[2:-1]

    for g in list(my_dict.items()):
        print(g)
```

The output from the unedited PDF file:

```py
('ClassLevel', 'Assassin 1')
('Background', 'Lone Survivor')
('PlayerName', 'None')
('CharacterName', 'Tumas Mitshil')
('Race ', 'Human')
etc...
```

The output when it was edited (I changed the ClassLevel, etc. completely in the PDF):

```py
('ClassLevel', '\\xfe\\xff\\x00C\\x00l\\x00a\\x00s\\x00s\\x00L\\x00e\\x00v\\x00e\\x00l')
('Background', '\\xfe\\xff\\x00B\\x00a\\x00c\\x00k\\x00g\\x00r\\x00o\\x00u\\x00n\\x00d\\x00r')
('PlayerName', '\\xfe\\xff\\x00P\\x00l\\x00a\\x00y\\x00e\\x00r\\x00N\\x00a\\x00m\\x00e')
('CharacterName', '\\xfe\\xff\\x00T\\x00h\\x00o\\x00m\\x00a\\x00s')
('Race ', '\\xfe\\xff\\x00R\\x00a\\x00c\\x00e')
('Alignment', '\\xfe\\xff\\x00A\\x00l\\x00i\\x00g\\x00n\\x00m\\x00e\\x00n\\x00t')
etc...
```

I know this is an encoding of some sort, and a few Google searches led me to believe it was in UTF-8 encode, so I attempted to decode the PDF when opening the file:

```py
fp = open(filename, 'rb').read().decode('utf-8')
```

Unfortunately, I am met with an error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    fp = open(filename, 'rb').read().decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

When I first made the PDF, I used Adobe Acrobat. However, I used Microsoft Edge to edit the file, which resulted in the problem I am facing. Here are the files:

[Original File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ZmvDrkWOke-YuFhfhWJUmi-Nf8bv3wZ/view?usp=sharing)
[Edited File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Leil3lFvDwEMpZa9zNm9URhDtflgcuMH/view?usp=sharing)

Is there any way to properly decode this? Is there a way to encode the edited pdf so it can be loaded into python without trouble? And if this is encoded, are there other forms of encoding, and how would I decode those?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's UTF-16 with a leading BOM.

Comment: As @mkl said, the value of the field is a unicode string starting with a byte order mark (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). If you use `value[2:].decode()` you can see the text you want, intertwined with `\x00`.

Comment: If I return to using my previous method I'll definitely give it a try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I was able to find a better solution. Instead of using pdfminer to open the PDF, I used PyPDF2. Somehow, it can read any PDF regardless of encoding, and it has a function that can automatically turn the fillable spaces into a proper dictionary. The result is a finer, cleaner code:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

infile = "Edited_CS.pdf"
pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(open(infile, "rb"))

dictionary = pdf_reader.getFormTextFields()

for g in list(dictionary.items()):
    print(g)
```

Regardless, thank you for all of your answers! :)

Comment: I am curious how PyPDF2 differs from pdfminer! I've created an issue on the pdfminer github to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem by using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC to edit the form fields. I've edited the form fields of `Edited_CS.pdf` using it and pdfminer.six returns the expected output.

Probably Microsoft Edge is causing this problem.

Comment: Very true, but I want it so it can accept any PDF saved from any application, thus I would require it to be properly decoded. However, I was able to solve my issue.